# PHP and MVC 3 in single IIS

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

Can we run php and MVC 3 application under single IIS 7. I have installed PHP in the IIS using PHP Manager. I also want to run asp.net MVC 3 application in same IIS Server. Is it possible to run both php and asp.net MVC   3 application under same wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do that. You won't be able to share sessions and such though, but you might have to change the IIS Application Pool Configuration in order for this to work properly.

Take a look at: 
[Can PHP and ASP.Net run together within the same web site in IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761769/can-php-and-asp-net-run-together-within-the-same-web-site-in-iis-7-5)