# Ajax Call from the Classic ASP page to PHP on the same server

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, asp-classic

I want to incorporate PHP in the current site written in Classic ASP on IIS. 
Is it possible to have the PHP running on the same server 
to be able making the the Ajax calls from the client side of the ASP pages to PHP scrips.
Right now I'm using XAMPP for PHP scripts.
If it's possible how it has to be configured? 
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761769/can-php-and-asp-net-run-together-within-the-same-web-site-in-iis-7-5

Comment: have u got solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  AJAX calls, for the most part, don't care if you are calling an ASP page, PHP page, or ASPX page they just open a connection to the URL.  The one caveat to this is that your ASP pages won't know about any Session or Global variables you have defined in PHP and vice versa unless you are persisting them to a cookie or a database.

As far as configuration goes there shouldn't be any. Assuming you have installed PHP on your server IIS will handle what handler takes care of what page (e.g. PHP is handled by the PHP ISAPI etc).