# Main website on ASP.NET C# with folder in PHP

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress, azure

I needed some help in understanding how i can get this setup completed. Due to the current setup of the website, we have a "/blog" that is powered by Wordpress PHP. We are looking to upgrade the website with ASP.NET C# for the main website "/" in a Windows Azure server but maintaining "/blog" on a Linux machine.

The service doesn't wish to use sub-domain for the blog in fear of losing too much SEO value that cannot be duplicated.

May i ask how can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15570/how-do-i-run-a-subdirectory-on-a-separate-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the php website a subfolder of your main ASP.NET site as described in [Create a Separate Site or Virtual Directory for PHP Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/create-a-separate-site-or-virtual-directory-for-php-content).

See also [Can PHP and ASP.Net run together within the same web site in IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761769/can-php-and-asp-net-run-together-within-the-same-web-site-in-iis-7-5)