# WordPress Inside Subapp Angular js and web api not working in IIS?

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, iis

I have created one application in the IIS. And then configure my wordpress site successfully and mapped my url as http://testwordpress.com

Inside that app I have created two sub-app and then publish my angular js app and
web API. After creating it URL of app is http://testwordpress/myapp. But my login from **API is not working**

But I was configuring html site inside http://testwordpress.com means my app and API working

So I don't know what is the issue?. Any Suggestions ?????

Answer (score 0):

PHP and .net not support inside IIS as it is sub folder logic.
So  **one solution is here. Solved my Problem.**
Follow this link and read out third answer ....

[Can PHP and ASP.Net run together within the same web site in IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761769/can-php-and-asp-net-run-together-within-the-same-web-site-in-iis-7-5)